# Scrapy, no puedo extraer los productos de una página. no está en response, cómo se puede solucionar?

Tags: python, fetch, data, scrapy

Probé de muchas maneras y al final encuentro el error, pero no sé cuál es la solución.

Quería obtener los productos de la página https://es.pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/

resulta que en response no aparece datos de los productos, lo probé con dos siguientes comandos:

`scrapy shell https://es.pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/`

`view(response)`
Y aparece la siguiente pantalla, que tiene un error en mientras haciendo fetching.

Alguien sabe cómo se solucionarlo? Muchas gracias...
[image: sin datos]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Pues en la página https://es.pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/ tiene 1317 productos con datos, son datos que quiero extraer, pero no aparece esos datos en ```response```. No sé qué puede faltar, probé :

-Aumentar ```DOWNLOAD_DELAY```.

-Poner ```USER_AGENT``` como un navegador chrome.

Pero sigue pasa lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy es una herramienta de extracción de datos que puede ayudarte a extraer información de páginas web. Sin embargo, si no puedes ver los datos que deseas extraer en la respuesta obtenida después de ejecutar el comando "view(response)", es posible que la página web utilice algún tipo de protección contra scrapers.

Una posible solución sería utilizar una cabecera de navegador falsa para hacer que Scrapy se presente como un navegador real y no como un scraper. Puedes hacer esto modificando el diccionario "DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS" en tu archivo de configuración de Scrapy.

También puedes intentar utilizar una herramienta de desarrollador del navegador (como la consola de JavaScript en Google Chrome) para ver qué datos están siendo cargados en la página y cómo puedes acceder a ellos desde Scrapy.

También puedes intentar utilizar otras herramientas de extracción de datos como BeautifulSoup, Selenium o PyQuery. Cada una de estas herramientas funciona de manera diferente, así que tendrás que investigar un poco para ver cuál se adapta mejor a tus necesidades.

Otra opción es intentar contactar con el administrador de la página web y preguntarle si puedes acceder a los datos que deseas extraer de alguna manera. Si la página ofrece una API, por ejemplo, podría ser más fácil acceder a los datos que deseas.

Comment: Probé modificar ```DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS``` pero no consigo obtener lo datos.
Las otras herramientas no creo que funciona tampoco, si están protegido los datos..
Necesito estos datos para hacer un trabajo universitario, entonces busco otras  páginas para mi necesidad, pero muchisimas gracias.